# How to update granular permissions in library

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions

I am site collection admin and also added with full control on the site.
We have library Lib1 with three folders (F1, F2, F3)

A user has set unique permission on F1 and have removed all full control rights and me from there.

Now, i could not even see the folder in library. I need to update the permissions of the folder.

How could i do it.

Comment: You can't, you need to have higher permissions. Either on the folder or as a policy on the web application

Comment: If you're the site collection admin on this site, you should have the ability to add yourself as an owner of the site and manipulate everything under that site from there.  Are you saying that the user removed you as a site collection admin?

Comment: Robert, could you please elaborate a bit what you have set about policy or give some url.